# How to merge splitted files in php

Tags: php

I use [HJSplit](http://www.hjsplit.org/php/) to split the files(say x.jpg into x.jpg.001, x.jpg.002,etc) and How to join this files with the help of php

Comment: check the answer my friend!

Comment: Actually HJ Split has a php file that will split